# Generic IBindingListView Implementations

Tags: .net, data-binding

Can anyone suggest a good implementation of a generic collection class that implements the `IBindingListView` & `IBindingList` interfaces and provides Filtering and Searching capabilities?

I see my current options as:

- Using a class that someone else has written and tested
- Inheriting from `BindingList<T>`, and implementing the `IBindingListView` interfaces
- Write a custom collection from scratch, implementing `IBindingListView` and `IBindingList`.

Obviously, the first option is my preferred choice.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I used and built upon an implementation I found on and old MSDN forum post from a few years ago, but recently I searched around again and found a sourceforge project called [BindingListView](http://blw.sourceforge.net/).  It looks pretty nice, I just haven't pulled it in to replace my hacked version yet.

nuget package: `Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView`

Example code:

```
var lst = new List<DemoClass>
{
    new DemoClass { Prop1 = "a", Prop2 = "b", Prop3 = "c" },
    new DemoClass { Prop1 = "a", Prop2 = "e", Prop3 = "f" },
    new DemoClass { Prop1 = "b", Prop2 = "h", Prop3 = "i" },
    new DemoClass { Prop1 = "b", Prop2 = "k", Prop3 = "l" }
};
dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingListView<DemoClass>(lst);
// you can now sort by clicking the column headings 
//
// to filter the view...
var view = (BindingListView<DemoClass>)dataGridView1.DataSource;            
view.ApplyFilter(dc => dc.Prop1 == "a");
```

Comment: +1 Five years later and this still looks like a great implementation.  I haven't found anything better that supports Sorting and Filtering out of the box.

Comment: damn, simple awesome !

Comment: It doesn't support Add or LINQ?

Comment: Anyone encountered this exception while using BindingListView? It just says `Ambiguous match found.`

Comment: There is now a respective Nuget package: `equin.applicationframework.bindinglistview`

Comment: Worked for me nearly 13 years later! Worked like a champ on a BindingSource. 
 `(myBindingSource.DataSource as BindingListView<MyClass>)?.ApplyFilter(x => x.Name.Contains(searchText));`

Comment: BindingListView has a bug with sorting in .NET 6. It crashes due to the "BuildValueTypeComparison" method, which emits IL directly. That IL code works in .NET Framework, but not in .NET 6. The bug can be fixed using the modification explained here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2411

Comment: @iCode casting a BindingSource as a BindingListView<MyClass> always returns null for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the help for your method 2 and 3
Behind the Scenes: Implementing Filtering for Windows Forms Data Binding

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4af0c96d-61d5-4645-8961-b423318541b4&displaylang=en

Comment: The code here doesn't actually work! The originalListItems value is never set and so the list doesn't reset correctly. As long as you know this you can add the code in yourself.

Comment: @chris: what do you mean the originalListItems value is never set? It's set via the OriginalList property! Or do I miss something?

Comment: Here is some more context for that link:    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winformsue/archive/2008/05/19/implementing-filtering-on-the-ibindinglistview.aspx

Comment: The current link for the article and the sample code is: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17914

Answer (score 1):

A couple of solutions I can think of:

1. The [SubSonic Project](http://subsonicproject.com/)  has a pretty nice implementation of `BindlingList<T>` which is open source. Although this might require using the entire SubSonic binary to use their implementation.
2. I enjoy using the classes from the [Power Collections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) project. It is fairly simple to inherit from one of the base collections there and implement `IBindingListView`.

Comment: Is there a more recent release of Power Collections?  Discussion page talks of updates for .net 4.0 in 2011, but the download page release is from 2007.