# How to filter datagridview by at least one parameter

Tags: c#, datagridview

Here is the situation. I have 3 textboxes(2 strings and 1 type of int), 1 combobox and 1 datagridview. I want to filter my gridview by at least one parameter. Source of my datagrid is a list. So far, the code below is my result, but is is not working.

```
var result = from UsersBySearchConditions in MatchedUsersSelected
where (UsersBySearchConditions.FirstName.StartsWith(txtFirstName.Text)
     || UsersBySearchConditions.LastName.StartsWith(txtLastName.Text)
     || UsersBySearchConditions.UserID == Convert.ToInt32(txtWorkingID.Text)
     || UsersBySearchConditions.WorkingDepartmentID == cbWD.SelectedValue)
     select UsersBySearchConditions;

dgvUserList.DataSource = result.ToArray();
```

Thanks.

Comment: check this link out ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501079/datagridview-filtering also have you considered using a DataTable it has a `Select()` method that you can be done easily in my opinion. aslo can you state whether results has any data in it after the linq `select call has been executed..?

Comment: @MethodMan Thanks, your redirected answer helped. I used this as a example: result = result.Where(usr => usr.FirstName.StartsWith(txtFirstName.Text.Trim()); and so on for the others.