# EF in WinForms: how to filter data in BindingSource/DGW (.Local.ToBindingList())

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-6

I generated an EF model (Database first) and DataSource following this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx

On my form I created BindingSource (bsUsers) and bound DataGridView to it.

Here is how I load data on form startup:

```
    _myDbContext = new MyDbContext();

    _myDbContext.Users.Load();

    bsUsers.DataSource = _myDbContext.Users.Local.ToBindingList();
```

It works, I can add and modify records using DataGridView and other bound controls.

But the thing I didn't figure out is how to filter data. For example I want to have textbox where I can type user name (or part of it) and it will hide all other records.

Looks like BindingList that is returned by ToBidingList() method doesn't support filtering?

I tried this

```
bsUsers.Filter = "Id = 1";
```

or

```
bsUsers.Filter = "Username like 'admin'";
```

But no effect. **UPD:** and `bsUsers.SupportsFiltering` is `false`.

I have googled but found only this topic [MSDN topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc753ca1-d24a-409e-a88c-459132697204/how-to-filter-datagridview-in-winforms-when-using-localtobindinglist?forum=adodotnetentityframework) where they suggest to filter data before loading (`Users.Where(...).Load()`), and that's not what I need. I want to load all records and then allow to filter it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Filter` property of the `BindingSource` only works with lists that implement the `IBindingListView` interface. Since `BindingList` only implements `IBindingList` (which has no filtering capabilities) the `Filter` property does nothing.

Either load your data into something like a `List<User>` and provide the bsUsers.DataSource with filtered elements of the list, e.g. `users.Where( u=> u.Id == 1 ).ToList()` or replace your BindingList by a list that implements IBindingListView. Possible pointers from here: [Generic IBindingListView Implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107/generic-ibindinglistview-implementations)

Comment: The problem with List<> (not sure about IBindingListView yet) is that I need to be able to modify/add/delete records (and save it to database some time later), it is not read-only.