# Bindingsource filter using DataGridView and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, bindingsource

I'm developing my first Winforms app using Entity Framework to access database. I have experience using `dataset` and `tableadapter`s.

I have a form with a `DataGridView` (DGV) on it, and I want to filter the displayed data.

In previous app, to filter data I used the filter property in the bindingsource because this allows me to add "SQL like" cmds to the bindingsource. Furthermore this will let me build a generic filter component to be attached to the DGV like the one in DevExpress. This is a requirement because I'm migrating a large scale application (600 tables, 400 views and 600 stored procedures) and I need to build up my generic libraries in order to improve my productivity.

I looked for this issue and find some answers around. One of the most accurate was in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23309112/ef-in-winforms-how-to-filter-data-in-bindingsource-dgw-local-tobindinglist/23309829#23309829?newreg=ae513ef6db5242d29c86db8a9afdefb8).

As the post says, the component that should be assigned to the `bindingsource.datasource` must implement the `IBindingListView` interface.

When I try to assign the `context.tableName.local` to the property the possibilities are calling `toArray()`, `toBindingList()`, `toList()`, and none of them implements the `IBindingList` interface.

The post resolution indicates that the `BindingListView` component (http://www.sf.net/projects/blw) solved the problem but I still don't realize how to pass a filter as a string. Maybe I'm missing something but the documentation (http://blw.sourceforge.net/) does not help.

Maybe someone could give some guidelines to solve the problem. Using Linq to filter is, at first, not a solution because I'll be attach to the fields in the model/table and I'm looking for something generic.

One last thing is that I want the ability to add/modify/delete the data in the DGV. This is not crucial because always I can set `context.tableName.Local.ToBindingList()` to the `bindingsource`.

Retrieving filtered data by adding `.where` clause before the `.load()` doesn't seem a solution because I need dynamic filtering and the load is done once as I could see in some other post (but maybe I'm wrong).

Dynamic Linq would be a solution but I have some issues when filtering dates, using wildcards and `startwith`/`endwith` methods.

Is it OK working with EF in such app?

Comment: `ToBindingList` doesn't implement `IBindingList`? I'm sure it does, or more accurately, the result does.

Comment: Yes it does, but I do not know how to filter data (by string)displayed in the DataGridView after assigning it to the BindingSource. For example, Dynamic Linq won't let me, and if I assign by doing ToList() method, the context.SaveChanges() doesn't save the new rows added to the DataGridView, but it saves modifications to existing rows.